Formalizing "finite or infinite" in Coq
In Coq, I am trying to formalize the notion of a finite or infinite sequence, e.g. of natural numbers: call it a run, and call pos a finite run.
I think I cannot use plain stdlib Streams since I have a possible base case: the first consequence, compared to Stream, is that my run_hd, run_tl, etc., up to run_nth must return options since I can have empty runs, but I guess that is not a problem.
The actual problem is that eventually I do not know how to define a usable predicate and/or computable function to determine/state/distinguish between finite and infinite runs.
Here is some minimal code that I hope is representative enough, where I am trying to have structural sub-typing, but I just cannot get to the bottom of it:
CoInductive run : Set :=
  | RunO : run  (* base for finite runs *)
  | RunS : nat -> run -> run.

Inductive pos : Set :=  (* structurally a finite run *)
  | PosO : pos
  | PosS : nat -> pos -> pos.

Definition IsFinRun (r : run) : Prop.
  Admitted.  (* HOW? *)

Coercion pos_to_run (p : pos) : run.
  Admitted.  (* easy *)

Coercion run_to_pos (r : run) : IsFinRun r -> pos.
  Abort.     (* HOW? *)

For example, among many variations, I have tried:
Definition IsFinRun (r : run) : Prop :=
  exists n : nat, forall m : nat,
    m <= n <-> run_nth m r <> None.

Coercion run_to_pos (r : run) :
  IsFinRun r -> pos.
Proof.  (* in proof mode to explore it *)
  unfold IsFinRun.
  intros H.
  destruct H.  (* ERROR:
    Case analysis on sort Set is not allowed
    for inductive definition ex. *)

(The same error, just on sort Type, happens if I replace Set with Type everywhere.  In fact, I do not understand why that error at all, given n is a nat.)
(I have tried to keep the whole thing as brief as possible, but I can post more/full code if necessary, just please let me know.)
What am I missing?  In particular, how could I fix/complete the code up to run_to_pos?  Thanks in advance for any help or insight.

Using your definitions, a run is finite if and only if it is in the image of pos_to_run, so you could define it this way (and this is a proposition because pos_to_run is an embedding, so you can represent this with a $\Sigma$-type). If you want a decidable criterion, then you'd need something like a coproduct of (inductive) lists and streams.

Thanks very much @NaïmFavier .  This indeed works: Definition IsFinRun (r : run) : Set := {p : pos | r = pos_to_run p}. -- OTOH, I had thought about the coproduct, but then I thought, maybe wrongly, that it would be less elegant than structural subtyping as well as less faithful to the informal progression and notions... anyway, as for decidability, I'd have thought working in Set was the critical factor: I am missing the distinction you are making in that sense.

Having $A : \mathrm{Set}$ does not guarantee that $A$ is decidable in the sense that $A \lor \neg A$ is inhabited. Assuming this for all sets $A$ (or more precisely the ones that are h-propositions) is postulating the law of excluded middle. Decidable propositions are classified by Bool.

"Decidable" is how I interpreted your "and/or computable function to determine/state/distinguish between finite and infinite runs". If you use your definition of run then you can only semidecide whether a run is finite.

The problem
Informally, we want a type of "finite or infinite sequences", henceforth "runs", with the following form:

The finite runs:

[]
[1]
[1,2]
[1,2,...,n]

and so on for all n.


The infinite runs:

[1,2,...,n,---]

for all n, for all possible infinite tails,
where every finite initial segment is a finite run.

A solution
(I have changed few names re the initial code to reflect a different interpretation of the terms.)
Here is some code that seems to do the trick, with the merits, I'd propose, that 1) it quite directly reflects the form of the requirement (the informal construction), and 2) it is very simple and effective to use down the line.
Essentially, finRun as a sigma-type instead of a Prop, and leveraging pos_to_run: then, from an element of finRun r, we can directly extract a (the) p corresponding to r, where p is an element of a plain inductive type, so easy to work with.
A crucial point is that we interpret RunE (and PosE) as the bottom of a finite sequence, while the head in RunN (and PosN) is the initial element of the (possibly infinite, for RunN) sequence.
That entails that the natural way to "progress" such sequences (construct a "next" element) is with append, not with cons.
(** A [run] is a possibly infinite sequence. *)

CoInductive run : Set :=
  | RunE : run                 (* bottom *)
  | RunN : nat -> run -> run.  (* initial+rest *)

(** A [pos] structurally is a finite [run]. *)

Inductive pos : Set :=
  | PosE : pos                 (* bottom *)
  | PosN : nat -> pos -> pos.  (* initial+rest *)

(** Conversions to [run] from finite. *)

Definition nat_to_pos (n : nat) : pos :=
  PosN n PosE.

Fixpoint pos_to_run (p : pos) : run :=
  match p with
  | PosE      => RunE
  | PosN n p' => RunN n (pos_to_run p')
  end.

(** Conversions from [run] to finite. *)

Definition finRun (r : run) : Set :=
  {p : pos | r = pos_to_run p}.

Definition run_to_pos r : finRun r -> pos :=
  fun h => let (p, _) := h in p.

(I am not an expert, and I am sure my presentation is at least clumsy: suggestions and objections, on my analysis as well as the code, are very welcome.)
[*] This solution is based on (my understanding of) an initial suggestion by Naïm Favier given in a comment to the question.

I have decided to mark this answer as a solution: I have found every answer and every comment very useful, thanks very much again to all those who have contributed, just, since I can accept one and only one answer, this is the one that eventually I find nearest to the desiderata in my original question.

Since the error you encountered is that you can't deconstruct a proof term whose type's type is Prop to construct the value whose type's type is Set, one ad hoc workaround is to use an inductive Prop with one constructor (which is the special case that can be deconstructed in Set or Type). You can define finiteness of a sequence as a "Prop with one constructor" IsFinRun as follows:
CoInductive run : Set :=
  | RunO : run  (* base for finite runs *)
  | RunS : nat -> run -> run.

Inductive pos : Set :=  (* structurally a finite run *)
  | PosO : pos
  | PosS : nat -> pos -> pos.

Definition tail_run (r : run) : option run :=
  match r with
  | RunO => None
  | RunS _ t => Some t
  end.

Inductive IsFinRun (r : run) : Prop :=
| isfinrun : (forall t, tail_run r = Some t -> IsFinRun t) -> IsFinRun r.

Fixpoint run_to_pos (r : run) (i : IsFinRun r) {struct i} : pos :=
  match r return IsFinRun r -> pos with
  | RunO => fun _ => PosO
  | RunS h t => fun i => PosS h (match i with isfinrun _ j => run_to_pos t (j _ eq_refl) end)
  end i.


With the following update Fixpoint run_to_pos (r : run) (i : IsFinRun r) {struct i} : pos :=   match r return IsFinRun r -> pos with   | RunO => fun _ => PosO   | RunS h t => fun i => PosS h (run_to_pos t match i with isfinrun _ j => (j _ eq_refl) end)   end i., that is performing the match inside the second argument of run_to_pos, you do not even need to use singleton elimination. This is basically the same idea as the inductive characterization of isFinRun in my separate answer.

This is my second attempt to solve the problem, it is completely different from the first.
Would it be fix the problem to pass in an upper bound of the length and a proof that that length is correct?
CoInductive run : Set :=
  | RunO : run  (* base for finite runs *)
  | RunS : nat -> run -> run.

Inductive pos : Set :=  (* structurally a finite run *)
  | PosO : pos
  | PosS : nat -> pos -> pos.

Fixpoint pos_to_run (p : pos) : run :=
  match p with
  | PosO => RunO
  | PosS x xs => RunS x (pos_to_run xs)
  end
.

Fixpoint run_to_pos_option (n : nat) (r : run) : option pos :=
  match n, r with
  | _, RunO => Some PosO
  | 0, _ => None
  | S n', RunS x xs =>
      match run_to_pos_option n' xs with
      | None => None
      | Some w => Some (PosS x w)
      end
  end
.

Definition IsFinRun (n : nat) (r : run) : Prop :=
  run_to_pos_ok n r <> None.

Definition safe_get (t : Type) (x : option t) (witness : x <> None) : t.
  destruct x.
  auto.
  assert ((None : option t) = None) by auto.
  intuition.
Defined.

Definition run_to_pos (n : nat) (r : run) (witness : IsFinRun n r) : pos :=
  let result_option := run_to_pos_option n r in
  safe_get pos result_option witness
.
```


@NaïmFavier, I took another crack at it ... and am now passing in the natural number bounding the length and a proof of its correctness from the outside instead of whatever wrongheaded thing I was doing before. This differs from the OP's approach of passing in an existential.

(1/2)  We have no way to guess the amount of fuel needed, to the point that, to preserve correctness, instead of option I'd try and use a three-valued result as in Some, None, Failed (equiv., an option of option), and parametrise the whole thing on a global hard depth limit: which I'd say is a common pattern in resource constrained environments.  (Would you agree with this "reading"?)

(2/2)  So, this solution quite makes sense to me, it is just a bit more concrete-level than I'd wish/hope: analogous to formalizing a discourse on arbitrary (unbounded) precision arithmetic with a multi-precision (hard-limited) specification...  OTOH, please correct me if I am mistaken, a fuel-based approach makes an IsFinRun fully decidable and effective, so I would end up needing that ingredient at some stage anyway, to the point that I might very well introduce it since specification time...  --  Need to think more about it/play more with it.  Thanks very much for now.

@JulioDiEgidio, Li-Yao Xia’s answer is better, I just tried a couple of things until something sort of worked.

Another way to approach the problem is to characterize isFinRun inductivelly and to define run_to_pos by structural induction on the proof of isFinRun. Notice that isFinRun r is used to justify termination of the Fixpoint but not to drive the computation. The computation is driven by the structure of r.
This is a good example for the application of the Braga method. The slogan would be: use a specific Prop bounded fuel instead of Type bounded fuel in nat .
CoInductive run : Set :=
  | RunO : run  (* base for finite runs *)
  | RunS : nat -> run -> run.

Inductive pos : Set :=  (* structurally a finite run *)
  | PosO : pos
  | PosS : nat -> pos -> pos.

Fixpoint pos_to_run p :=
  match p with
  | PosO     => RunO
  | PosS n p => RunS n (pos_to_run p)
  end.

Inductive isFinRun : run -> Prop :=
  | iFRO :     isFinRun RunO
  | iFRS n r : isFinRun r 
            -> isFinRun (RunS n r).

Definition is_RunS r :=
  match r with
  | RunO     => False
  | RunS _ _ => True
  end.

(* partial inverse of RunS *)
Definition RunS_inv r : is_RunS r -> run :=
  match r with
  | RunO     => fun C => match C with end
  | RunS _ s => fun _ => s
  end.

(* We get the exact sub-term "s" of "RunS n s" *) 
Goal forall n s, RunS_inv (RunS n s) I = s.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed.

(* partial inverse of isFinRun (RunS _ _), BEWARE of structural decrease *)
Definition isFinRun_inv {r} (fr : isFinRun r) : forall hr : is_RunS r, isFinRun (RunS_inv r hr) :=
  match fr with
  | iFRO       => fun C => match C with end
  | iFRS _ _ h => fun _ => h
  end.

(* Inversion of isFinRun (RunS _ _) *)
Definition isFinRunS_inv {n r} (fr : isFinRun (RunS n r)) : isFinRun r :=
  isFinRun_inv fr I.

(* We get the exact sub-proof "fr" for "iFRS n r fr" *) 
Goal forall n r fr, isFinRunS_inv (iFRS n r fr) = fr.
Proof. reflexivity. Qed. 

Fixpoint run_to_pos {r} (hr : isFinRun r) { struct hr } : { p | pos_to_run p = r } :=
  match r return isFinRun r -> _ with
  | RunO     => fun _  => exist _ PosO eq_refl
  | RunS n r => fun hr => let (p,hp) := run_to_pos (isFinRunS_inv hr) in 
                          exist _ (PosS n p) match hp with eq_refl => eq_refl end
  end hr.


Thank you, very interesting.  Indeed, already what is happening in run_inv, how you concretely achieve that kind of "partiality", is totally new to me...  I will certainly read more about this Braga method.

I did edit the initial comment for better names and two goals explaining why we get partial inverse functions.
